# echo command not preserving \n character when storing output in a variable - bash shell script

Tags: newline, preserve

I'm trying to retrieve the newline character when echo command stores the data in a variable. can someone please help me

when I run the echo -e, it gives with output as expected from commandline

```
bash>testfile='INFO\nERROR\nWARNING'
bash> echo -e "$testfile"`
INFO
ERROR
WARNING
```

but, when I try to store the output in a variable I'm missing newline character.

```
bash>testoutput=`echo -e "$testfile" | grep 'WARNING\|ERROR'`
bash>echo $testoutput
ERROR WARNING
```

appreciate the suggestions

Comment: Works for me on gentoo. What version of grep are you using?
`% grep --version` gives
`grep (GNU grep) 3.1`

Comment: I have grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Comment: Might need to update your distro.

Comment: Upgrading the grep version might take a while,, is there an alternate solution for the original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/how-to-add-newlines-into-variables-in-bash-script) on the unix stackexchange.

Looks like the newlines are in there, `echo` just doesn't want to print them for some reason. Check out `printf` instead.

```
brundage@fatty ~ $ testfile='INFO\nERROR\nWARNING'

brundage@fatty ~ $ echo -e "$testfile"
INFO
ERROR
WARNING

brundage@fatty ~ $ testoutput=`echo -e "$testfile" | grep 'WARNING\|ERROR'`

brundage@fatty ~ $ printf "$testoutput\n"
ERROR
WARNING
```